# Extremely slow Mongo $group stage

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, database-performance, query-performance

I have a following mongo aggregation pipeline that I am trying execute on a collection containing 6 million documents ( each document has 30 key-value pairs on an average). My concern is that the group stage takes extremely long (to the order of minutes).
The stages are in this order: match -> sort -> project -> group -> skip -> limit. All the query keys, which are part of match and sort, are correctly indexed. I also tried running the same pipeline without group stage and it completes in less than a second. I also did explain on this aggregation pipeline and my indexes are properly used.

Is there anyway i can further improve the performance of group stage for my below pipeline? or is there any other alternative that I can use to perform a distinct query, along with pagination (skip/limit) on a key inside my collection? I looked at db.collection.distinct, but it has an upper bson size limit of 16 MB.

```
[ 
{ "$match":{ "dSource":{ "$in":[ "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33" ] }, "$and":[ { "dirty":{ "$exists":false } } ] } }, 
{ "$sort":{ "_id":1 } }, 
{ "$project":{ "sampleKey":1 } }, 
{ "$group":{ "_id":"$sampleKey" } },
{ "$skip":0 },
{ "$limit":200 } 
]
```

Comment: As a note, `$project` immediately followed by a `$group` which only includes the projected field is [actually voided in the optimize stage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#projection-optimization) of the pipeline. You're not reducing the amount of input MongoDB takes, by this because since `_id` is the only output, then that's the only "input" which is taken. Not the whole document. Kind of touched on in that manual, but's that's what it really means. `$group` output is an "implied" SELECT statement in SQL terms.

Comment: That said, the `$sort` is also superfluous here and probably does more harm that good. "String matches" of the `$in` is not wise, and would be better served by "numeric" values in storage and a specific "range" condition. The actual `$group` itself at this state is solely dependent on the hardware processing it. If it's "a lot of data" ( regardless of how many distinct values in result ), then it's a "a lot of crunching" to do. The only thing that solves that part is to ["get a bigger boat!".](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=We%27re%20Gonna%20Need%20a%20Bigger%20Boat)

Comment: On "out of the box" solutions, if you are looking for a "distinct list" from a lot of data, then perhaps you should be storing the "distinct" values in a separate collection by adding them with "upserts" each time something gets added to the "detail" collection. I probably should also note that *"I also tried running the same pipeline without group stage.."* actually means this is not yet an "aggregation" at this point in time. In fact the preceeding stages are basically considered the same as `.find({ .. },{ "sampleKey": 1 }).sort({ _id: 1 })`. Which only starts doing things when fetching.

Comment: @NeilLunn, thanks for you responses. Yes, to be precise, i meant the preceding stages were ran using .find({}). Also, I do understand the implicit optimization that mongo performs, but my pipeline example above is to be more "explicit" in what i am trying to achieve here. 
I did think of having another collection where i cache my distinct values, but that is not truly scalable for my use case, since i can have n number of columns at runtime depending on the data definition. IMO, caching in an another collection also defies schema-less behavior of mongo.

Comment: Let me summarize since to appear to be missing the point. *"Can I **optimize** this process for the `$group` and speed it up?"*. **NO**. It is what it is. Either throw more hardware at the problem or re-architect to make it a non-issue. You cannot "add an option" or "setting" or anything else that speeds this up, other than what I have already outlined.

Comment: @NeilLunn, Understood, thanks ! What kind of hardware config do you propose to bring such a query's response time to under 10 seconds? Does that mean that group performance in mongodb is exponential (amount of data vs hardware) ? The hardware config that i have is 32 gb RAM, 8 CPU and 512 gb HDD.

Comment: I recommend you start ["distributing the load"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/). Recommendations of any sort and essentially any "database performance tuning" or "hardware setup" are **not** "programming based questions" are are therefore **off-topic** for Stack Overflow. If there was something you could do in the code, then we would tell you. Anything not related to the code, is not for discussion here.

Comment: i wasn't asking for a hardware setup here :). I wanted to get an idea of how a group improves as (if at all) i add more shards. With my configuration, i have three shards, but i am still not happy at all with the "software" performance i get from mongodb using group stage.